# Folder Dialog Box in ASP.Net

Tags: c#, asp.net

How we can achieve the below business requirement.

-->The End user needs to "select a folder path using Aps.net"

Whereas selecting a file can be achieved by `<input type="file" />`, but how to browse a folder path.

Thanks 
Abdul

Comment: there's no folder selection - it could be a regular text box.

Comment: Populate a dropdown.

Comment: something which you like this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2302257/how-could-i-select-folder-or-file-from-the-asp-net-web-application

Comment: Most important piece of information is missing: *Why do you need to do that?* Usually there is no need to be even able to that.

Answer (score 4):

It is not possible to select folder from a website using native HTML+JS. You can only select a **file or list of files for upload**, but not a folder itself. Usually you won't even get see the original file path of the file that was uploaded, and you just **cannot get direct access to the user's filesystem**. Web communication is based on HTTP requests and is stateless, so there would be no way the server could access the folder on the user's (remote) PC. And for security reasons, not even JavaScript on client can do so.

Flash and Java could pick a folder and work with it on client, but those technologies are practically deprecated on modern web.

Only way this could work reasonably would be if the **ASP.NET Server was running on the user's PC**. Then the user could manually input the path to a given folder and the server could then access it directly. But when the server is running somewhere else, this is unfortunately out of the question.

Comment: There is a way: You can link programms to specific protocolls, the same way you can link them to filetypes. So if you could get the client side to install your little programm, it might react to a properly prepared link. But as you said, this is a security issue no mater how you slice it.

Comment: Yes, that is an interesting idea! But it wouldn't really feel secure to the user, especially when trying to open a non-http protocol on web causes a dialog warning window on most browsers.

Comment: Actually this pattern is in use. Steam uses the "steam://" protoll for everything. All those links on your desktop? Technicalyl internet links (steam://rungameid/289070) Granted steam does provide it's own WebBrowser (the steam client) and I never teted what happens if I click on Play on a Storepage I opened in my webbrowser. I am pretty sure if we we install it with Adminsitrative Rights, we can get around any warning/set up a proper default. And at that point, it is the Admins decision :)

Comment: Didn't know that! But the scenario I described is rather that when you are on a website which has for example a `magnet:` protocol link, it first shows a security alert the user has to confirm before the external application is opened. But it is possible the alert can be overridden not to display.

Comment: Thanks for your Reply.
But how we can achieve this functionality.
Also i saw few websites are using "Browse folder" dialog..

Comment: Those websites however must have used plug-ins to achieve this functionality (Flash, Java). You can technically use those, but the functionality will not work in most modern browsers unfortunately